# No headphone sound in HP Spectre x360 13-w030ca Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 16.10, headphones

I've been struggling for several days with this issue. According to many posts the HP Spectre x360 works great with 16.10 and it does but this is the only problem i have (although a big one). Plugging in the headphones make speakers mute (ok) but no sound ever comes out from the headphones. I have Dual Boot with Windows 10 with Fast Startup disabled and headphone works ok in Windows (last Realtek drivers installed) so hardware problem is discarded.

Some more info
The laptop detects when the jack is connected and disables speakers. I can "see the sound" in headphones section with pavucontrol and all seems right with alsamixer, no muted stuff
Tried changes with hdaJackRetask, alsa-base.conf and alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf but just trying my luck with those since it's not clear what should i change
I also tried reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio

My alsa info http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2b...7cd776c87009c6

Any clues on this? I'm totally lost...

Thanks everyone!

Update: this thread also has some info https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354645&p=13615839#post13615839 it seems that new kernels don't seem to solve this issue for this particular Spectre model

Comment: I didn't realize it at first, but for me, not only does the headphone jack not output sound (though it does turn off speakers), but the top speakers don't work either -- only the underside ones output sound. This is the bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189331 which also contains reports of the headphone problem.

Comment: I have also played with the hda-analyser extensively with no results.

Comment: You may find this article interesting: http://www.asyndetic.com/2013/04/11/on-debugging-intel-high-definition-audio-in-linux-part-i/ Though putting it into action seems like more than a hobby than a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior on same model 13-w030ca running kernel 4.10.1-2-default (Tumbleweed/kde). Yes, it works fine under windows 10. I'm getting no sound out of the jack to either headphones or high impedance (~50kOhm) amp input though I agree it is definitely detecting the change from speakers when I plug in anything.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is more of a follow on statement. Next time please add text of this nature in as a comment, not an answer.